# datetime-picker sale detrás del modal

Tags: bootstrap, angularjs, bootstrap-3

Estoy dando soporte a una aplicación que usa AngularJS y Bootstrap v3.3.7, estoy agregando un datetime-picker  a un formulario que esta en un modal, pero el datetime-picker se ejecuta detras del modal, Se vé así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo en el modal para el datetime-picker:

> ```
>                         <div class="input-group date" >
>                              <label>Fecha Visita</label><br>
>                                 <input style="width:130px" type="text" name="fechaVisita" id="fechaVisita" class="btn btn-default btn-xs ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="visitaSel.fechaVisita" placeholder="Fecha Visita" datetime-picker="" date-format="yyyy-MM-dd"> <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i>
>                         </div>
> ```

claro esta que este bloque esta dentro del class="modal-body"

Saludos cordiales

Comment: te sugiero usar el z-index: "z-index: 2000!important"

Comment: @Diego Avila gracias voy a leer de este tema por que no lo he usado. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Estas utlizando alguna libreria para datepicker?

Comment: @cjara estoy usando angularjs-datetime-picker.min.js y angularjs-datetime-picker.css

Comment: Éste es un issue abierto en la libreria https://github.com/kineticsocial/angularjs-datetime-picker/issues/31, uno de los comentarios aconseja usar z-index, te recomiendo en caso de querer migrar usar una libreria con mas actualizaciones y comunidad como https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/, espero te sirva. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo menciono @Diego Avila, agregue estas líneas en el CSS del datatime-piker.css y funcionó:

```
.ui-timepicker-container{ 
     z-index:1151 !important; 
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos por sus aportes.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que por defecto bootstrap utiliza `z-index: 1055`.

Tienes que poner uno más arriba (un número más grande). Asi lo hice yo usando un datepicker angular material

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {

  z-index: 2000 !important; //cualquier z-index: por encima de 1055 sirve
}
```

Te toca con el inspector mirar bien el modal.